# Get Make Home Page checkbox back for page content item in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am working on learning Orchard.  I have got my development machine in a state where it will not load the home page.  I get a 404 error with this message...

Server Error in '/OrchardLocal' Application 404

I realized that it is because no content item is set as the home page.  However, the checkbox for making a page (or anything else) the home page is not showing in the edit page screen.

How do I fix this?  I need the Make this a Home page checkbox back or some other way to accomplish the same thing.

Is there a way to do this in the database directly (which I realize is a hack but might let me move the ball forward on the problem).

I thought I would mention the EXACT exception thrown by the error is "The controller for path '/OrchardLocal/' was not found or does not implement IController."

Any help is appreciated.  If I can't figure this out it seems I will be back to doing Orchard from scratch (new pull, new db etc) which seems to happen EVERY time I try to learn Orchard.

Here are the Parts I have on the Page Content Type.  This is probably not the default list because I have been messing with it to get it fixed.
Common
Publish Later
Title
Autoroute
Body
Containable
Navigation
Identity
Menu

For the record I added the blog Module to the site and added a blog.  But same behavior when I create a blog...no Make this the Home page and no way to set the permalink.

Comment: It sounds like there is an error during the rendering of the autoroute part.  These errors should be getting logged to the app_data folder.  Can you check there to see if there are any clues?

Comment: Thanks Brandon Joyce. Unlike OP, I am not sure why I get the 404 error. But after checking log I see: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): Access to the database file is not allowed. [ 1914,File name = C:\Path\To\Orchard.sdf,SeCreateFile ]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the AutoRoute Part attached to the Page Content type.

Comment: I got excited when I read this because I thought that would be it.  But, unfortunately, that was not it.  The Page DOES have the AutoRoute Part attached.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your User has the permissions to set a content item as the homepage

Comment: I am getting this behavior with the Super Admin account that is created during setup.  But just to be sure, I checked the permissions of the Admin role and I could not find a set content item as a homepage permission.  But I confirmed that this Admin role has all effective permission.  I only have two users (including the super user), they are both in the administrator role and I am getting this behavior logged in as either one.

Answer (score 0):

To set an item as a homepage just set its permalink to an empty string.

Comment: Piotr, I cannot make the permalink an empty string because that option is also gone when I try to edit the page.  It is really weird.  I have the permissions and I believe the page type has the appropriate parts added (I am going to add that list to the question).   The only thing I did was delete the original page that was created by default but only because i had setup a new page.